# Anime about a girl who crashes on a planet and chased by an indestructible evil robot

Tags: story-identification, anime

It's probably from 80-90s. I remember that a girl probably crashed on some remote planet and was chased/hunting an evil robot that was indestructible.
She was fighting with him at some villages. I think that robot was called Nemesis or something (not 100% here) and was looking like wearing big hat on his head (like sombrero or conical hat).

As far as I remember the art style was very similar to [*Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind poster*](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/nausicaa_of_the_valley_of_the_wind) (although it's not that anime for sure).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I think I've found it - it was probably: [*Iria: Zeiram The Animation*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/432/Iria__Zeiram_The_Animation) (sorry about misguide about robot name) - I need to double check it, but I think it turned out I've seen only couple episodes of it, not complete story.

> Iria is the story of a girl and the Alien being she loves to hate. The series begins with her brother, Gren, taking a job. He is a bounty hunter, and one well known for his incredible skill. Iria, being a skilled apprentice bounty hunter herself, tags along. What is the job, one might ask. It is to find out what has happened to the crew and cargo of a Space Station. Needless to say, nothing is as it seems, and the war between Iria and Zeiram begins in earnest.

### Trailer

Comment: Congrats on finding it! Don't forget to accept your answer in about 33 hours.

Comment: It seems I've seen 2nd episode only, but it's 100% this anime.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it wasn't a remote planet but a floating island with a castle on it? In that case, it probably was [_Laputa: Castle in the Sk_y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_in_the_Sky). After the success of *Nausicaä*, the legendary Studio Ghibli was founded, and *Laputa* was the first movie of the new studio. Often *Nausicaä* is counted as the first Ghibli movie, because many of the later Ghibli masterminds where involved, but that movie was technically "pre-Ghibli".

The story revolves around a young girl, Sheeta. She's hunted by agents who are after her crystal pendant. On the run from the agents, Sheeta meets a young boy named Pazu. He is searching the floating city in the sky that his father once saw. Maybe Sheeta has something to do with this city and its powers?

The robot would be part of the automated defense system of the floating castle that Sheeta and Pazu run into.

Comment: thank you for your response, but it's not this movie. It was more sci-fi / future alike (although the villages they were fighting were looking just normal) - a girl had a suit similar to the one from Nausicaä's poster.